# Access registers of the PLIC interrupt controller from another driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I want to access the registers of PLIC interrupt controller from my driver.

I tried to map in my driver the address of the PLIC, I took it from the device tree. Then I access the registers with `readl()`, `writel()`. Is this the right way? Knowing that PLIC and my device  share the same APB.

```c
void __iomem *plic_regs = ioremap(plic_phys_add, size);
pr_info(" PLIC_ENABLE_PER_HART : %#x\n", readl(plic_regs+PLIC_ENABLE_PER_HART));
```

Comment: *"Is this the right way ?"* -- No.  Just because you're not using an object oriented language does not mean that object oriented concepts cannot be used.  Specifically the concept of data encapsulation.  The driver for the PLIC interrupt controller "owns" the registers of that device.  All access (or use) of those registers should be through that driver.  You're trying to violate that ownership.  Even though there's nothing stopping you, that can lead to bad consequences.

Comment: @sawdust I wanted to read the PLIC registers without making any changes,  but I only read 0's. Is this the correct way   in terms of code   ?  not to mention the consequences.

Comment: You are doing something very wrong. Probably you have to formulate your real problem in the Q.

Comment: @0andriy I want to read the PLIC registers inside my driver . 

What's wrong with the code   ? why it is wrong and what's the solution  even  dangerous one .

Comment: Interrupt controller is not just *a device*. Have you read Datasheet? Are you sure registers are you trying to read have no side effects? Have you checked what the driver is doing?